# Variable image height in Nested Grid UWP

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I want to show multiple images one after one vertically. That's why I've implemented Nested grid. It works fine for same height images. but different height images it looks odd because in nested grid height set according to first item height. Here is my code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
            <Grid x:Name="ImageGridViewItem"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Padding="0,0,0,0"
                  Background="#FAFAFA"
                  BorderBrush="#E6E6E6"
                  BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Background="#FAFAFA"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      BorderThickness="1">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           Width="{Binding ImageSource.PixelWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                           Height="{Binding ImageSource.PixelHeight, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                      Background="#F5F5F5"
                      Padding="0,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ImageNoTxtBox"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               Margin="0,4,0,0"
                               Padding="0"
                               FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                               FontSize="10"
                               FontWeight="Normal"
                               Foreground="#252525"
                               Text="{Binding ImageNo,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

```
<GridView x:Name="ImagesGridView"
      Grid.Row="5"
      Margin="12,0,2,0"
      Padding="10,10,0,0"
      Width="{Binding MainGridViewWidth}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList, Mode=OneWay}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}">
</GridView>
```

Image

[image]

Comment: Hi, can the following method help? Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the row height of GridView depends on the first item, if you want to show the Variable height in GridView, you can try to use [WrapPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel) from Windows Community Toolkit. Before using it, you need to add **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls** nuget package and then override the ItemsPanel of GridView, for example:

.xaml:

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

<GridView x:Name="ImagesGridView"
            Grid.Row="5"
            Margin="12,0,2,0"
            Padding="10,10,0,0"
            Width="{Binding MainGridViewWidth}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList, Mode=OneWay}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}">
    
     <GridView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <controls:WrapPanel Name="VerticalWrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    
</GridView>
```